# Fill missing values in DataFrame

Tags: pandas

I have a `dataframe` that is either missing two values in two columns, or one value in one column.

```
         Date    30  45   60    90 
0  2004-01-02  0.88  0.0  0.0  0.93
1  2004-01-05  0.88  0.0  0.0  0.91
...
20 2019-12-24  1.55   0  1.58  1.58
21 2019-12-26  1.59   0  1.60  1.58
```

I would like to compute all the zero values in the `dataframe` by some simple `linear` method. Here is the thing, if there is a value in the 60 column, use the average of the 60 and the 30 for the 45. Otherwise use some simple method to compute both the 45 and the 60.

What is the pandas way to do this? [Prefer no loops]

**EDIT 1**
As per the suggestions in the comment, I tried

```
df.replace(0, np.nan, inplace=True)
df=df.interpolate(method='linear', limit_direction='forward', axis=0)
```

But the `df` still contains all the `np.nan`

Comment: may be replace 0 with `np.nan` and use [`df.interpolate`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.interpolate.html) , guessing since the example is not very clear

Comment: That would have been great if it worked. See Edit 1

Comment: i thought you needed `axis=1` since you wanted column to column.

Comment: Duh! Tha'ts it! Thanks!